# SQL - Same Table join to calculate profit from last entry

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table of transactions for various products. I want to calculate the profit made on each

```
Product                Date           Profit     Incremental Profit
--------------------- --------------------------- -----------
Apple                 2016-05-21      100
Banana                2016-05-21      60
Apple                 2016-06-15      30
Apple                 2016-08-20      10
Banana                2016-08-20      5
```

Can I create a SQL query that can group based on product and give me incremental profit on every date for each product. For example on 21-05-2015 since it is first date so incremental profit will be 0. But on 15-06-2016 it will be -70 (30-100).

The expected output is:

```
Product                Date           Profit     Incremental Profit
    --------------------- --------------------------- -----------
    Apple                 2016-05-21      100    0
    Banana                2016-05-21      60     0
    Apple                 2016-06-15      30     -70
    Apple                 2016-08-20      10     -20
    Banana                2016-08-20      5      -55
```

Comment: Add the expected result as well. (Copy, paste, and adjust!)

Comment: Are the rows always sorted by data? I mean can i take just last entry, and not look for last entry by date?

Comment: @jarlh I have added the expected output table.

Comment: @JanWalczak The rows will need to be sorted since the incremental profit will be based on difference of profit between two consecutive dates.

Comment: i ask if your records are added with sorted date. Earlier date will always be higher in table?

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe try use trigger after update?

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can use this.

```
select 
    a.product
    ,a.date
    ,a.profit
    ,isnull(a.profit - (select top 1 x.profit from profit x where x.product = a.product and x.date < a.date),0) as profit
from PROFIT a
order by product, date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Product NVARCHAR(50), Date_ DATETIME, Profit INT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES
('Apple'  ,               '2016-05-21',      100),
('Banana',            '2016-05-21',      60 ),
('Apple',             '2016-06-15',      30 ),
('Apple',             '2016-08-20',      10 ),
('Banana',            '2016-08-20',      5  )


;WITH CTE
AS
(   
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Date_) RowId
    FROM @Tbl

)


SELECT 
    CurrentRow.Product ,
    CurrentRow.Date_ ,
    CurrentRow.Profit ,
    CurrentRow.Profit - ISNULL(PrevRow.Profit, CurrentRow.Profit) 'Incremental Profit'
FROM 
    CTE CurrentRow LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT CTE.Product ,CTE.Profit, CTE.RowId + 1 RowId FROM CTE) PrevRow ON CurrentRow.Product = PrevRow.product AND
                                                                              CurrentRow.RowId = PrevRow.RowId
ORDER BY CurrentRow.Date_
```

Result:

```
Product     Date_       Profit  Incremental Profit
Apple       2016-05-21  100     0
Banana      2016-05-21  60      0
Apple       2016-06-15  30      -70
Apple       2016-08-20  10      -20
Banana      2016-08-20  5       -55
```

Edit:

```
UPDATE @Tbl
SET [Incremental Profit] = A.[Incremental Profit]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        CurrentRow.Product ,
        CurrentRow.Date_ ,
        CurrentRow.Profit ,
        CurrentRow.Profit - ISNULL(PrevRow.Profit, CurrentRow.Profit) 'Incremental Profit'
    FROM 
        (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Date_) RowId FROM @Tbl) CurrentRow LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Date_) + 1 RowId FROM @Tbl) PrevRow ON CurrentRow.Product = PrevRow.Product AND
                                                                                                           CurrentRow.RowId = PrevRow.RowId
) A
WHERE
    [@Tbl].Product = A.Product AND
    [@Tbl].Date_ = A.Date_
```

Comment: Thanks for the soution. This works. Is it possible to update this into the existing table rather than doing a select here.

Comment: @Swati Yes, change `@Tbl` with your table

Comment: Yes I did change the table but how do I update the records. I think the update syntax has to be with in the query. So assuming Tbl has a column 'IncrementalProfit' then what will be the change in this query. Apologies but I am new to SQL and your solution is a bit complex :)

Comment: Answer is updated. change `@Tbl ` with `your existing table`.